# How Cast works in TV(at recivers end)

Tags: python, android, chromecast, dlna

I want create dummy TV-cast program that
Can be discovered by an android Cast app
as A-tv(like Samsung-smarttv) in the list
And can stored the casted content in mp4.

It tried for week but didn't understand anything..

Github:.
-Cohen3 python(not understand documentation).
-dlanp.
-pychromecast.
-Chromecast-device-emulator.

A simple explanation a how both devices communicate and transmit data
Using DLNA/Upnp protocol

After installation of Cohen using setup.py file

$ cohen --plugin=backend:FSStore,content:/path/to/your/media/my_file.mp4

And also
$ cohen --plugin=backend:ElisaPlayer(#as media Renderer)

Did as said in documentation but, I didn't understand how/where the start cohen3 in python or terminal

Please guide me if am wrong at any part.

Thanks for reading the stupid question.
Waiting for response.